# DJANGO HEROKU :django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory:

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

i have pushed my django application to heroku
and when i tried to fireup the url where my application is 
i just got this error

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "accounts_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."is_active", "accounts_user"."date_joined" FROM "accounts_...
```

so i have figured out that the issue is with migration so i tried to run the makemigrations command in heroku 
but unfortunately it returned as a failure  with an error message

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration posts.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

so what i have tried is i have completely removed the migrations and database and runnned makemigration  and migrate command in my local server and then i pushed it back to heroku but still its of no use
my local is running perfectly fine

i'm not sure where exactly the migrations issue is , in my heroku django application
i want to remove the previous migrations and have a clean database 
but i have no idea on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue yesterday. I was using Django rest and sqlite3 DB.
To solve that error I have clear all migration and delete a migration folder and clear DB file. After that, I have run migrations specific for that module and then run migrate command then it works fine for me. I hope it will work for you as well.

e.g.

```py
$ python manage.py makemigrations module_name

$ python manage.py migrate module_name
```

Comment: when i tried to run makemigrations and the app name still im facing the same error

Comment: Have you delete migration folder and database file and pycache files??

Comment: Am i supposed to remove those files and push it to heroku or run makemigrations and  migrate commands in local after removing them and push ?

Comment: yes try that once and do migrations per module. It worked for me.